# Как разместить img по центру div?

Tags: css

имеется div target

```
.target {
    margin-top: 2vmin;
    margin-left: 1vmin;
    margin-right: 1vmin;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10vmin;
    border-top-color: salmon;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: salmon;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

внутри которого вставлена картинка

```
.target img {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
    max-height: 14vmin;
    max-width: 14vmin;
}
```

Как сделать чтобы картинка была по центру а не так ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.target {
  /*изменения в стилях*/
  position: relative;
  /*изменения в стилях*/
  margin-top: 2vmin;
  margin-left: 1vmin;
  margin-right: 1vmin;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10vmin;
  border-top-color: salmon;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: salmon;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.target img {
  /*изменения в стилях*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*изменения в стилях*/
  max-height: 14vmin;
  max-width: 14vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  <img src="https://cs6.livemaster.ru/storage/73/64/49fcdfe67c695e932b5b0483c87e.jpg" />
</div>
```

Вариант ДВА `flex`

```css
.target {
  /*изменения в стилях*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*изменения в стилях*/
  margin-top: 2vmin;
  margin-left: 1vmin;
  margin-right: 1vmin;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10vmin;
  border-top-color: salmon;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: salmon;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.target img {
  max-height: 14vmin;
  max-width: 14vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  <img src="https://cs6.livemaster.ru/storage/73/64/49fcdfe67c695e932b5b0483c87e.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/627749   вот смотри - без всякого node.js

Comment: @MaximLensky, при чем тут `nodejs`, там просто подробнее. К `node` это не относиться...

Comment: а  то что ты мне подсунул решение на node и ешё объявил то что возможно имеется решение ..а в твоём примере не было его но и кстати с примера на тостер тоже не универсально ...та как если обновить страницу то появляется conot get

Comment: @MaximLensky [зайди в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.parent img {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png" />
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.parent img {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 121px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png" />
</div>
```